# how to handle overlapping points in zingchart js

Tags: overlapping, zingchart

if I have the same point for two plots in a line chart of zingchart js when I hover on that point I got only a single plot value other is getting hidden
behind one

Answer (score 0):

If active areas for tooltips overlap perfectly, only one value will show. crosshair-x is the only tool which shows all values as you can see in this [demo](https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/create/FGRP3VQ7)

[image]

Comment: actually i my chart there are many lines i.e 20 to 30 line plots are there which are generated dynamically so if i used crosshair-x then all points are display like you shown in reply , and there for my hole ui get disturb , that's why i need some other solution for this 

thank you for reply

Comment: can we do something like check overlapping points and if the point is getting overlapping we will change the move point slightly so we can hover on that also

Comment: No, its not going to work, because you may have 20 points there, how would you make space for all? The only option, i think, is to just check values in rules, but even that i'm not yet sure it will work.